# How does one get access to the Flash object's vars in IE?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, object, mootools

Is there a way in IE Browsers to access the Flash object? In this case it is made with mootools swiff. It´s working fine in all other browsers, because they can wrap this object correctly.  But it does not work in IE.

Here is the script:

```
var swfObj = $('mbImage').getElement('object');
swfObj.get('data');  <--- Thats not working in IE
```

Comment: Is swfObj null or does swfObject.get() fail?  You need to me more precise about what isn't working.

Comment: No, he returns an object, but I cannot access it´s vars. The Problem is the same in all IE Versions. In IE he returns just "object", and everywhere else it is "object HTMLembededElement". I also tried the nonMootools ways to get the Object right like "window.document[thePlayer.id]", but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a general issue with flash objects in IE - it's very difficult to extend them with MooTools methods, actually MooTools 1.2 is not doing so, and never will.

That said, on the upside, new **beta of MooTools 1.3** has a lot of amazing modifications in its core, and now **flash objects are extended with MooTools methods**.

Please find the latest beta at [GitHub](http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/tree/1.3b1.1) or download the official one from the [MooTools Blog](http://mootools.net/blog/2010/04/27/mootools-1-3-beta-1/)